# tqdm progress bar showing up on two lines

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

In Jupyter on Windows my tqdm output always shows up broken into two lines. I have yet to find a parameter combo that fixes it. Simple code that reproduces problem:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
for ind in tqdm(range(1000), position=0, leave=True):
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: tqdm two lines]

Based on some stuff online I've tried installing `colorama` package and it makes no difference. If possible I want the code to be usable in ipython, terminal, etc as I am putting it in a package that is used in many platforms.

Comment: I think it's some artifact of Jupyter notebooks. Normally with `tqdm` it all goes in one line.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your import to : `from tqdm.auto import tqdm`

Comment: Yes, this works in Jupyter! Unfortunately in other contexts (e.g., Spyder) using `tqdm.auto` causes the progress bar to lock at zero: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/1098  It looks like I'm stuck picking the least bad problem (I really need my solution to work in most environments and if it shows up on two lines in Jupyter that is better than it locking up at 0% in Spyder).